# The simplest way to cut off unnecessary dots in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, data-mining

I have coordinates of dots (x,y) stored in `1206x2` matrix called `data`. The command `plot(data(:,1),data(:,2))` gives that picture:
[image: data plot]

I've found maximums in my data with `findpeaks` command:

```
[pks,loc,smth] = findpeaks(data(:,2));
```

And then plot them on previous graph:

```
plot(mod(:,1),mod(:,2),mod(loc,1),pks,'o')
```

[image: data with maximums]

So, the question is: what is the simplest way to cut off maximums which I do not need, I mean the maximums below red line on this picture:
[image: third plot] 
UPD:
The best way I've found by now is to use "MinPeakDistance" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `envelope` built-in function:

```
% generate signal
x = 1:200;
y = x.*sin(x/5).*sin(3*x);
% get its envelope
npeak = 2;
[yupper,ylower] = envelope(y,npeak,'peak');
plot(x,y,x,yupper)
```

[image: envelope]

and then you can just add/subtract constant from this envelope to shift it along y-axis.

Comment: Ok, if you are looking for an Octave solution you shouldn't tag the question for Matlab unless you specifically ask for something compatible with both.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to skip points in a plot is to make them `NaN`. I am going to assume that you have a variable `redline` with Y values for all the X values you have such that `redline(loc)` is going to return the cutoff at the peaks locations. You can ignore `peaks` beyond the curve as:

```
>>pks(pks < redline(loc)) = NaN
>>plot(mod(:,1),mod(:,2),mod(loc,1),pks,'o')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've painted red line in gimp

Answer (score 0):

For the signal you've shown it's actually pretty straightforward. If I have some signal, similar to yours,

[image]

You can find the positive peaks where the sign of the derivative is equal to one

```
dy = [NaN, diff(y)];
pks = sign(dy) == 1;
t_pks = t(pks);
y_pks = y(pks);
```

[image]

Comment: So, it does not cut off peaks I needn't